# How do I speed up my snake?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So this part of my js is moving the snake.

```js
if(direction === "right"){
    newX ++;
    } else if(direction === "left"){
    newX --;
    } else if(direction === "up"){
    newY --;
    } else if(direction === "down"){
    newY ++;
```

When I tried incrementing it by 2 when score is more than 10, it breaks its body.

[Here's the code pen link](http://codepen.io/gamalielhere/pen/qbyNmb)

Comment: Your codepen doesn't work.  It doesn't even have HTML in it for the canvas.  We're gonna need more code than that.

Comment: @zero298 I added the html and css. Sorry about that.

Comment: You could clear your current `setInterval` and start it again with a shorter interval.

Comment: @rupps how would you go with it while adding it to an if statement? repeat the paint?

Comment: @MikeC I tried 
    if(score >= 10){
    clearInterval(loop_game);
    setInterval(render, 45);
    }

it just stopped the game after reaching 10 pts.

Comment: I see you're drawing into the canvas, so best would be to draw a line from the old position to the new position

Comment: @rupps how do I do that?

Comment: forget about it, now that you fixed your codepen and it works, I better understand your problem, you should do what @MikeC suggests: Just clear the interval and set it with a faster speed. See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MikeC suggests, just modify your speed. You can define this function:

```
  function runGame(newSpeed) {

      if(typeof loop_game !== "undefined") 
           clearInterval(loop_game);

      loop_game = setInterval(render, newSpeed);
  }
```

Then at the start of the game, you call this function:

```
function startGame(){
    .
    .
    .

    runGame(speed);

}
```

And later on, when you need to increase the speed:

```
if (speed>10) {
    speed -= 10;
    runGame(speed);
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZJRdQ

I modified your codepen to make it work and scored 18 points :) can u beat me?

Answer (score 0):

Handle the cases when `newX` overflows past your boundary (which I assume is 10):

```
newX = (newX + 2 < 10) ? newX + 2 : 10;
```

This will check whether adding 2 to `newX` will make it more than 10. If it doesn't, then it will add 2. If it does, then it will simply set `newX` to 10.